# Append XML responses in Python

Tags: python, xml, api

I am trying to parse multiple XML responses in one file. However, when I write a responses to file, it shows only last one. I assume I need to add append somewhere in order to keep all responses.

Here is my code:

```
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#loop test 
feins = ['800228936', '451957238']



for i in feins:
   rr = requests.get('https://pdb-services.nipr.com/pdb-xml-reports/hitlist_xml.cgi?report_type=0&id_fein={}'.format(i),auth=('test', 'test'))

   root = ET.fromstring(rr.text)
   tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

tree.write("file.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
for i in feins:
   ...
   tree = ET.ElementTree(root)

tree.write("file.xml")
```

to (note the indentation):

```
for i in feins:
   ...
   tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
   with open("file.xml", "wb") as f:
      tree.write(f)
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for the quick response. I tried something similar. However, when I tried your suggestion I am getting following error:

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: @MarkoNestorovic Sorry, about that: it's not `a`, it's `wb`. Edited.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I tried wb and I am getting the same result, only last response, instead of both.